# Better solution than spinlock

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, spinlock

I'm currently revising for an exam and came across this question:

> Under what circumstances is a spinlock a suitable implementation for a
>   lock? When would it be a bad choice of implementation? Describe a
>   better solution and write a pseudo-code definition for it.

I can answer the question about the un/suitability of spinlocks, but I am absolutely stumped what constitutes a "better solution" and how to implement that in pseudo-code.  I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The fact that you know spinlocks are "unsuitable" in some circumstances implies that you must know there are other kinds of locks. You can answer the question using any other type you know.

Comment: +Alex D You're right. It's just sometimes I get quite overwhelmed with my revision I just sometimes lose the plot.

Comment: What a weird question?  How can you write pseudo-code for a kernel lock which, when it is blocking something, prevents execution of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do some investigation into topics like "Critical Section", "Mutex", "Semaphore", "I/O Completion Ports" and think about mechanisms for posting waiting threads.

Comment: Yes, this is useful. I don't really know how I didn't think of at least semaphore or mutex to begin with. The pressure of finals, I guess!